# Server Side rendering in mongo with dust

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dust.js

Is it possible to fetch data from MongoDB and render a html template on the server side itself for a node-js project?

As of now in my serverside js file I've done the following.

```
//Failing array will be populated by a db.find later on.
var failing = [
    { name: "Pop" }, 
    { name: "BOB" }
];

/*Now i have to send a mail from the server for which I'm using nodemailer.
 Where do i store the template ?  This is what I've done in the same file */

var template = "<body>{#failing} <p>{.name}</p> {/failing}</body>"

// Add this as the body of the mail and send it.
```

I'm not sure how to render the data and how to get it displayed. I'm aware storing the template in the variable isn't right but I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your template is that short, you can store it in a variable without problem. Obviously, you can store it in a file also.

Let's say you decide to store it in a file `index.dust`:

```
<body>{#failing} <p>{.name}</p> {/failing}</body>
```

Now, in your node controller you need to load the file and generate the html content from it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');

// Read the template
var src = fs.readFileSync('<rest_of_path>/index.dust', 'utf8');

// Compile and load it. Note that we give it the index name.
var compiled = dust.compile(src, 'index');
dust.loadSource(compiled);

// Render the template with the context. Take into account that this is
// an async function
dust.render('index', { failing: failing }, function(err, html) {
    // In html you have the generated html.
    console.log(html);
});
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.dustjs.com/guides/rendering/) in order not to have to compile the template every time you have to use it.